# Normalize special character in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete

I whish to normalize data in autocomplete removing all special characters but i don't know how to normalize this character "-" to a whitespace

I use VCS as code editor

I tried %20 but it doesn't help

```
var accentMap = {
      "è": "e",
      "é": "e",
      "-": "%20"
      };

    var normalize = function (term) {
      var ret = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
        ret += accentMap[term.charAt(i)] || term.charAt(i);
      }
      return ret;
    };
```

Comment: Just use a space? `"-": " "`

Comment: I tried " " and ""   but this but doesn't match

Comment: You could try to [normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) the string before mapping against your `accentMap`. So all the characters all have the same unicode form.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with notepad++ and encode the file int UTF8 and it does works ! with a whitespace " " So the problem came from VCS